# Что лучше для простейшей 2D графики на адроид?

Tags: java, android, графика, производительность, 2d

использование движка или написание своей графики в родной среде?
если нужно просто перемещать 2-5 спрайтов, но быстро и возможно с динамичной прозрачностью и масштабированием.
 (в Android Studio новичек)